# Calling a Web API from Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnet-httpclient

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

I have been using this tutorial to learn how to send and retrieve data from a web `API`. However is there another way without using `Tasks` and `await`? Sometimes my requests are taking a long time to return when others are relatively quick.

Are there any other tutorials that may help? What is the best way to call my web `api` client to login? I feel I shouldn't be using `await` and `async` for this sort of thing but could really use some help.

Comment: You should be using await and async (or some threading model) for any long running method.  This prevents the UI from freezing up until the call returns.  With that said, this question is not specific enough to give you a good answer.

Comment: Well my requests are general just to load small amounts of data into a datagridview or similar so they are not long running methods. How would I write an API call to get some data in a similar way to the tutorial but without await and async?

Comment: @user3427148 More than 30ms is considered long.  Most Http requests fall into that category. It's painful at first but you just need to get used to using Async methods.

Comment: I think this is answer you are looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716174/call-and-consume-web-api-in-winform-using-c-net

Answer (score 4):

just download microsoft http api library from nuget manager to your project and use httpClient

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `HttpClient` if you like and it is supported even in older versions of `.NET`, and you would not need to worry about tasks or threading. `HttpClient` also allows you to get the result `async` but you would need to provide a `callback` to be called when the result is ready.

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Having said that, I agree with John comments above that you should use `await` and `async`