# Call and consume Web API in winform using C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, asp.net-web-api

I am beginner and creating winform application. In which i have to use API for Simple CRUD operation. My client had shared API with me and asked to send data in form of JSON.

API : `http://blabla.com/blabla/api/login-valida`

KEY : "HelloWorld"

Value : { "email": "user@gmail.com","password": "123456","time": "2015-09-22 10:15:20"}

Response : Login_id

How can i convert data to JSON, call API using POST method and get response?

**EDIT**
Somewhere on stackoverflow i found this solution

```
public static void POST(string url, string jsonContent)
{
    url="blabla.com/api/blala" + url;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseURL);
    request.Method = "POST";

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";

    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    long length = 0;
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            length = response.ContentLength;
            
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
//on my login button click 
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CallAPI.POST("login-validate", "{ \"email\":" + txtUserName.Text + " ,\"password\":" + txtPassword.Text + ",\"time\": " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt") + "}");
}
```

I got exception that says "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can take a look at the following docs tutorial:

- [Call a Web API From a .NET Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

But as an answer, here I will share a quick and short a step by step guide about how to call and consume web API in Windows forms:

1. **Install Package** -  Install the [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) NuGet package (Web API Client Libraries).

   Open Tools menu → NuGet Package Manager → Package Manager Console → In the Package Manager Console window, type the following command:

   ```
    Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
   ```

   You can install package by right click on project and choosing Manage NuGet Packages as well.
2. **Set up HttpClient** - Create an instance of [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and set up its [`BaseAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and [`DefaultRequestHeaders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8). For example:

   ```
    // In the class
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Put the following code where you want to initialize the class
    // It can be the static constructor or a one-time initializer
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4354/api/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   ```
3. **Send Request** - To send the requests, you can use the following methods of the [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8):

   - GET: `GetAsync`, `GetStringAsync`, `GetByteArrayAsync`, `GetStreamAsync`
   - POST: `PostAsync`, `PostAsJsonAsync`, `PostAsXmlAsync`
   - PUT: `PutAsync`, `PutAsJsonAsync`, `PutAsXmlAsync`
   - DELETE: `DeleteAsync`
   - Another HTTP method: `Send`

   **Note:** To set the URL of the request for the methods, keep in mind, since you have specified the base URL when you defined the `client`, then here for these methods, just pass path, route values and query strings, for example:

   ```
    // Assuming http://localhost:4354/api/ as BaseAddress 
    var response = await client.GetAsync("products");
   ```

   or

   ```
    // Assuming http://localhost:4354/api/ as BaseAddress 
    var product = new Product() { Name = "P1", Price = 100, Category = "C1" };
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("products", product);
   ```
4. **Get the Response**

   To get the response, if you have used methods like `GetStringAsync`, then you have the response as string and it's enough to parse the response. If the response is a Json content which you know, you can easily use `JsonConvert` class of [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) package to parse it. For example:

   ```
    // Assuming http://localhost:4354/api/ as BaseAddress 
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("product");
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(response);
    this.productBindingSource.DataSource = data;
   ```

   If you have used methods like `GetAsync` or `PostAsJsonAsync` and you have an [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) then you can use `ReadAsAsync`, `ReadAsByteArrayAsync`, `ReadAsStreamAsync`, `ReadAsStringAsync, for example:

   ```
    // Assuming http://localhost:4354/api/ as BaseAddress 
    var response = await client.GetAsync("products");
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>();
    this.productBindingSource.DataSource = data;
   ```

**Performance Tip**

- [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) is a type that is meant to be created once and then shared. So don't try to put it in a using block every time that you want to use it. Instead, create an instance of the class and share it through a static member. To read more about this, take a look at [Improper Instantiation antipattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

**Design Tip**

- Try to avoid mixing the Web API related code with your application logic. For example let's say you have a product Web API service. Then to use it, first define an `IProductServieClient` interface, then as an implementation put all the WEB API logic inside the `ProductWebAPIClientService` which you implement to contain codes to interact with WEB API. Your application should rely on `IProductServieClient`. (SOLID Principles, Dependency Inversion).

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Answer (score 14):

Just use the following library.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp

GitHub Project: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp

Sample Code::

```
    public Customer GetCustomerDetailsByCustomerId(int id)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:3000/Api/GetCustomerDetailsByCustomerId/" + id);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("X-Token-Key", "dsds-sdsdsds-swrwerfd-dfdfd");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
        JObject customerObjJson = json.CustomerObj;
        var customerObj = customerObjJson.ToObject<Customer>();
        return customerObj;
    }
```

Comment: where is the reference of *jsonData* object?

Comment: @Zeeshanef Sorry there's a fault. Edited successfully. Now it should not throw any compiler error.

Answer (score 5):

- Use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert data into JSON
- Use [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to POST data

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example using an online REST service (https://northwind.vercel.app) which allows interaction with Northwind API.

This example uses [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [`JsonConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm) to get or post data. Here is a very quick example:

1. Install [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nuget package. And add the following using statements to your form:

   ```
   using System.Net.Http;
   using Newtonsoft.Json
   ```
2. Define an instance of the HttpClient, at class level:

   ```
   private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   ```
3. To send a **GET** request, for example getting list of all data:

   ```
   var url = "https://northwind.vercel.app/api/categories";
   var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
   if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
       var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(content);
       dataGridView1.DataSource = categories;
   }
   ```

   You can also use other overloads of Get, like GetStringAsync, GetStreamAsync, and etc. But GetAsync is a more generic method allowing you to get the status code as well.
4. To send a **POST** request, for example posting a new data:

   ```
   var url = "https://northwind.vercel.app/api/categories";
   var data = new Category() { Name = "Lorem", Description = "Ipsum" };
   var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
   var requestContent = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");
   var response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestContent);
   if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
   {
       var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       var createdCategory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(content);
       MessageBox.Show(createdCategory.Id.ToString())
   }
   ```

To learn more and see some best practices or see an example without JsonConvert, see my other post.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/path/to/post/to");
 
var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("site", "http://www.google.com"));
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("content", "This is some content"));
 
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```