# How to send POST requests for site Api?

Tags: c#

I learn Api for web application and use C# for send requests. Api work with Json format, and I use this code for send POST:

```
private static string Post(string Url, string Data)
    {
        var req = WebRequest.Create(Url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Timeout = 100000;
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        var sentData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(Data);
        req.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
        var sendStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
        sendStream.Close();
        var res = req.GetResponse();
        var receiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        //Кодировка указывается в зависимости от кодировки ответа сервера
        var read = new Char[256];
        var count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
        var Out = String.Empty;
        while (count > 0)
        {
            var str = new String(read, 0, count);
            Out += str;
            count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
        }
        return Out;
    }
```

I use it like this, but it is not working:

```
POST(@"https://mysite.ru/api.php/methodApi?id=2091&access_token=mytoken", "\"parameter\": \"value\"");
```

I understand right that, parameter send in Data? I never work with any API, may be doing something wrong?

Thanks for answers and sorry for my english.

Comment: [Call and consume API in winform using C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716174/call-and-consume-api-in-winform-using-c-net)

Comment: Your using an legacy way to perform this action also refer to the following for newer ways to do what your after [http-request-with-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working with WebClient