# POST request implementation

Tags: c#, json, winforms, post

I need to implement a `post` request in a `c#` `winform` application of my project. Earlier to that I just have implemented `get` requests. I have checked that the API URI is working well (I checked it using Postman). I never implemented POST requests in the past. The `get` requests I implement using the following code:

```
WebClient n = new WebClient();
string uri = "API_URI";
string json = n.DownloadString(uri);
```

**Now my requirement is to download `json` string using `post` method with an "apikey" with its value which I need to provide while calling the URI.**

When I am using the above code, it is searching the "API_URI" in my local application directory.

Any direction, sample code and or tutorial will be much appreciated. Please help me with that.

Comment: You can actually generate a c# code from postman.Click on `Code` under `Save` button (right from `Cookies`).

Comment: [Call an consume Web API in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32716351/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the call tested in Postman, as a starting point use the "Code" link in PostMan to generate your call using RestSharp so that you can test it and further refine it.

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string uri = "API_URI";
string json = "{some:\"json data\"}";
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "apikey");
string response = client.UploadString(uri,json);
```

this is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstring?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use POST method in this way

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string uri = "API_URI";
var reqparm=new NameValueCollection(); // Used for passing request perameter
reqparm.Add("some","json data");
response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(uri, "POST", reqparm));
```

I hope this will help you.