# create rest Apis Service in Winforms (.net framework)

Tags: api, winforms, restful-url

I have Windows App (.net framework) need to send data from app to web site by Apis, but need Apis in Winforms not from another app ,I'm using windows forms (.net framework 4.7)

Comment: If you "need to send data from app to web site", then check out `HttpClient` and see how to make HTTP requests with it. Calling/consuming an external web site/service does not require "create rest Apis service".

Comment: [Call and consume Web API in winform using C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32716351/3110834).