# secure multiuser authentication for winforms app using cloud database

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, authentication

I don't know much about SQL but i'm trying to make a simple application that would take multiple users. The problem is that the  only resources I've found to try and learn how to make a proper authentication window for a desktop application show only locaL databases and pretend that local databases would be accesible to the whole world. Additionaly, I don't want to locally be hosting my own SQL server for both security concerns, and because a different service would be able to properly provide what i need.

From what I understand I simply need a way for users to enter the data, compare it to the existing data, see if the usernames and passwords match and then authentication. The issues are: I don't know how to configure or work with cloud based databases, I don't know much about hashing and preventing SQL-injection nor do I know how to prevent any security concerns when it comes to SQL.

On top of that, the product I'm working on will eventually have to work almost like google drive where people can share some of their data with others, giving them access as editors and viewers to some of their info which would also be stored on the database... there will be lots of columns for each user.

Finally, I also will eventually have to add to my product a phone version, but I'm planning to just make a phone application or website which will take info from database and convert it into app version.

Overall, I'm just trying to make a simple but secure authentication method for my app because I cannot find a single solution that explains a proper way to do it.And i don't want it to be locally hosted.

Comment: I have created Windows Forms desktop applications which used MS Access databases as a local db.  But, I also have created a Winforms applicaiton that used Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) as a Service that used Restful http to communicate with a remote SQL Server db.   This technology is old, and I'm not sure that it is supported beyond .Net Framework 4.8.   I used VS 2017, .NET FX 4.8 and Entity Framework 6.0 to create my winforms application.  Look for "WCF Multi-layer Services Development".  WCF Services can be hosted in the Winforms application while only the database is remote.

Comment: I think what you want/need is not a WinForms application to login but rather a REST service that does the authentication against your DB in the Cloud (To avoid exposing the connection string to get to the DB), then you'll be able to access your WinForms app after login

Comment: I want to connect an azure api with connection string to the client side db and then that links to database which contains all user info, this should prevent any connection string exposure, ill store the passwords there with hashing + salt and hopefully it should run well. Any tips for connecting an API and database to wpf app... (I switched over to WPF for better support)

Comment: WPF vs. WinForms: there's no difference in support for Web API; Azure Active Directory; etc. They're just UI Frameworks.

Comment: Look at this post for example: [Call and consume Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32716351/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (WPF app), I managed "users and visitors" (SP entities), and the distribution of the application's output (charts and reports) via SharePoint (SP) Online, using the CSOM object model / interface (and C#) to directly connect my app to the "cloud" (i.e. SharePoint).

SharePoint is "backed" by SQL Server, but from a user perspective, it is "lists" (that are more palatable).

As for SP itself, you can *easily* create (sub) "sites" that serve as homes for different users, groups, subjects, etc.

In your case, you could maintain a "list of users" in SP, and access / update it from your app. You could even download the entire list for "offline" processing.